# Configurar RED multiples conexiones

Tags: redes, router, configuración, wifi

Muy buenas. Trabajo en una pequeña empresa y hemos configurado la RED entre mi jefe y yo. Evidentemente tiene problemas. Pongo abajo un esquema de la configuración que estoy probando en la actualidad, me sigue dando problemas cuando al router 2 se conectan muchos clientes. Tengo contratados 600MB de vodafone, aunque el speedtest me da 120Mb o menos en el router 1, y bastantes menos en el router 2. Pongo un pequeño esquema de la configuración:

```
**INTERNET <-fibra-> ROUTER 1 <-rj45-> ROUTER 2**


**ROUTER 1** Linksys Ono (192.168.0.1)
-> wifi 5 o 6 clientes
-> cable RED -> SWITCH Cisco ->
Switch CISCO:
-> Impresora
-> PC Despacho
-> MAC Estudio
-> cable 30 metros -> ROUTER 2 (2o piso)


**ROUTER 2** TPlink Archer C5 (192.168.1.1)
-> wifi invitados: ancho de banda limitado a 512k subida, 2Mb bajada. 25 clientes de media.
-> wifi profesores: ancho de banda limitado a 2Mb ssubida, 20Mb bajada. 3 clientes.
```

Mis preguntas son: En el router 2 tengo dos redes wifi con la esperanza de que la red de profesores sobreviva aunque colapse la de invitados, pero creo que esto no sucede pues colapsa el router en si, y toca reiniciarlo. ¿Se solucionaría esto si conectara por cable los tres ordenadores de profesores? ¿Se solucionaría sustituyendo los routers por otros de más calidad? ¿Se me escapa algo, está muy mal configurado?¿Y si quito el router 2 y voy hasta el piso de arriba?

Esta es la primera vez que me toca formular una pregunta. Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda o aporte, pues llevamos ya mucho ensallo error sin llegar a una solución.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Tu diseño y tipología, para el uso que parece que haces  - no lo has concretado - puede ser funcional, suficiente.

Parto de la base de que solo tienes dos problemas en la red, uno es caída del servicio de acceso a Internet por WLan, y el otro es bajo ancho de banda. El resto de accesos por cable, doy por hecho que funcionan correctamente a pesar de algunos no concretados, con ancho de banda bajo.

#### previos

Antes de nada de sugiero que amplíes el esquema, añadiendo las velocidades de sincronización de los cables ethernet. Comprueba físicamente que todos  sincronizan a `1Gbps Full Duplex`. De lo contrario revisa cableado o incluso me plantearía sustituir dispositivos ( routers / switches) si no son capaces de hablar a esa velocidad. Los dispositivos finales como ordenadores  de sobre mesa no hace falta que sincronicen a 1Gbps, pero si que lo conozcas.

#### sobre caída del servicio WLAN en router [Tplink Archer C5](https://www.tp-link.com/es/service-provider/wifi-router/archer-c5-v4/#overview)

Este router se puede catalogar como router domestico, pues no hay especificación en el producto que hable de limitación de usuarios por WLAN. Como tampoco habla en ningún momento del numero de radios disponibles. Encontraras routers mas profesionales que si hablan de esa característica.

Por el uso que parece que le deis, no es un router adecuado. Tenéis que buscar uno que disponga de mas radios ( que no quiere decir antenas) y que haya sido diseñado para el lugar que lo utilizáis ( colegio, sala grande, poli-esportivo...)

Si andáis muy perdidos en comentarios hablamos de Marcas.

Incluso es posible que necesitáis un sistema de [itinerancia Wifi](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itinerancia#Itinerancia_en_redes_wifi). Actualmente bastantes marcas ya venden ese tipo de producto.

Ten en cuenta que el medio de intercambio de datos no es guiado, son ondas de radio. Son muy susceptibles a las interferencias, incluso de las peores, que son muchos usuarios cerca entre ellos y emitiendo a la vez. Podrás comprobarlo que cuando hay 1 usuario conectado el sistema funciona correctamente.

Solo por ultimo intentar que la gente se diversifique por las bandas disponibles. Repartidos entre `2Ghz` y `5Ghz`.

#### sobre speedtest que no dan valor deseado

- Revisar y aprovisionar cableados entre dispositivos a `1/1 Gbps`
- Buscar servidores de pruebas confiables y cerca físicamente. Provar en mas de uno distintos.
- Aun así , si no obtienes resultados positivos, desenchufar todas la conexiones del `router FTTH`, conectar un PC conocido y potente directo, por cable ethernet a `1/1Gbps` y repetir las mismas pruebas.
- Si el problema persiste, intentad utilizar el menor numero de switches y routers, o intentad reducir numero de routers cambiando-los por switches.
- Por ultimo, si aun no hay buenos resultados, configurar la OLT de accesso `FTTH` en modo `bridge`, poniendo vosotros vuestro router.

Deseando haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me fue de gran ayuda! En cuanto acabe con todo lo que me aconsejas te diré si se ha solucionado.

"Podrás comprobarlo que cuando hay 1 usuario conectado el sistema funciona correctamente." +1 TOTALMENTE.

En cuanto al Router, me podrías aconsejar uno?

Comment: Cualquiera de la serie unify de Ubiquity te serive, igual que la serie WAP de Mikrotik tambien. Ubiquity es mas facil de configurar que Mikrotik, pero ambos hay tutoriales por internet...A mi gusto pondria Ubiquity

Comment: Gracias! Pinta muy bien. Lo pediré online. Solo por confirmar, quito el Router 2 y pongo este conectado por RJ45, correcto?

Comment: SI, por ejemplo!

Answer (score 0):

Esta semana estoy probando a poner ambos routers en modo "bridge". A ver si los problemas persisten.

Repito que cualquier ayuda es muy bien venida.
Gracias.